# Getting error ReferenceError for a function that is defined lower than it's usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've read that you should keep your Javascript at the very bottom of your page. However when I do this I get a `ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined` error since I'm referencing it before it's usage. I have it wrapped in document.ready but still doesn't work.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDialog()">Add New User</a>

$(function() {
    function showDialog() {
        $('#dialog-AddUser').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: your function is wrapped in an anonymous function. remove it and it should work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    function showDialog() {
        $('#dialog-AddUser').show();
    }
}
```

You got scope issues here. Not at all related to document loading. Remember that, whenever you declared/created something inside a function it is local to that function. Move it to outside where the whole document can see it.

Simply write

```
 function showDialog() {
            $('#dialog-AddUser').show();
        }
```

Should work.

Even if you write this function inside document ready, your function again localised to that particular ready function and become invisible to outside.

Comment: Scope was the issue! Thanks for the fast help.

Comment: If you want to retain the jQuery ready wrapper, you can just expose the showDialog function to the global scope like this:

$(function(){

  window.showDialog = function(){

    $("#dialog-AddUser").show();

  }

})

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined in the context of an anonymous function:

```
$(function () {
    function showDialog() {
        $('#dialog-AddUser').show();
    }
}
```

So `showDialog` cannot be called from outside the context of that anonymous function.

The solution here would be to add the click event handler from inside the function

```js
$(function () {
    function showDialog() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $('#dialog-AddUser').show();
    }
    $('#my-clickable-link').click(showDialog);
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="my-clickable-link">Add New User</a>
```

Then ultimately you don't need the `showDialog` function, just another anonymous function as the click handler.

```js
 $(function () {
    $('#my-clickable-link').click(function() {
      $('#dialog-AddUser').show()
    });
});
```

```html
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="my-clickable-link">Add New User</a>

<div id="dialog-AddUser" style="display:none;">Hello!</div>
```